# Is there a way to input my Qr-Code input from an external scanner (Windows Forms C#)

Tags: c#, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I need to get my input from an external USB QR-Code scanner to my windows forms application, but i have **no idea** how to start. I'm a beginner in c#, and i've tried looking online for solutions. Would it be smart to use a textbox and clear it each scan? I also heard some poeple talk about opening a console from your windows forms app? If you guys know any better way, please tell me!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Does this external USB QR-code scanner come with an SDK, or does it send keystrokes like a keyboard?

Comment: Thanks for answering! It has keystrokes like a keyboard. And at the end of the scan it 'presses' ENTER

Comment: So have a textbox for that input in your WinForms app?

Comment: Alright thanks, i was looking if there might be a better way since its for a final school project. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Yes, you can intercept `KeyPress`es on the form. That is going to be more difficult.

Comment: Routing a barcode/QR scanner to a regular text input is pretty standard, from what I've seen. Treating them as a keyboard is much simpler than dealing with a proprietary SDK. I *think* some scanners can be programmed to send a special character or key sequence as the start of their input--if that's an option, you can use it to distinguish regular keyboard input from scanner input. You'll have to read the manual to find out if it's an option for your scanner.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into it!

Answer (score 0):

I need to give QR code as a input to my form and resultant of the QR Code value should be auto filled in text box.